# XML files with DTD and XSD to HTML coversion

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, xsd, dtd

I have the documentation for the aircraft i`m flying in my airline as XML files with associated DTD files. Our library person use a special program from the manufacturer to convert these xml files to pdf. but the generated pdf files are not user friendly. So I suggested that we maybe can convert these XML files to XHTML and generate a simple documentation website for the pilots with easier navigation for the books.

I tried to figure out the schematics of the DTD and XML files but it seems too complicated.

Any suggestions on how to do convert these files to HTML?

I searched through google about this issue but most search results didn`t give any help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question is way out of scope for SO.  Please read the [faq] and [ask] to understand what types of questions are appropriate.

Comment: XSLT would most likely be your best option. You should have someone experienced with XSLT, XML, and DTD analyze your data to see what kind of effort you are looking at. What kind of documentation is it? I have a lot of experience with ATA (maintentance) data (SGML/XML), flight ops data, DTD, and XSLT. I can take a quick look if you'd like. My email is in my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DTD defines the tags in the XML. Without knowing what type of XML the file is, converting it to HTML will be hard if not impossible. XML can be basic and common like XHTML or Open XML but is often custom made. In XML you can make your own tags and that makes it hard to convert without tag data.

Typically, the easiest way to convert XML to some other Markup is by using an XSLT transform. If you can't find one you could write your own.

If you're looking at a complex DTD you probably have complex XML. A transform may not be easy in that case but is probably your best option.